# plotting list as graph error

Tags: python, list, plot

I am trying to plot a graph with the y-axis a function of two lists but I get an error. Note that time, firstlist, and secondlist all have the same length

```
plt.plot(time, (firstlist[i]**2 + secondlist[i]**2) for i in range(len(firstlist)))
```

The error I get is:

```
SyntaxError: Generator expression must be parenthesized if not sole argument
```

Where have I missed the parentheses?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
plt.plot(time, [(firstlist[i]**2 + secondlist[i]**2) for i in range(len(firstlist[1:]))])
```